# Illegal assignment from sObject to Id

Tags: apex, master-detail

I'm trying to insert two master-detail lists at the same time. I'm looking through Bob Buzzard's blog post: http://bobbuzzard.blogspot.com/2012/03/create-parent-and-child-records-in-one.html Where he uses this snipit to create an Account and Contact.

```
Account acc=new Account(Name='Blog Acc 8', Master_Id__c='Blog Acc 8');
Contact cont=new Contact(FirstName='Bob', LastName='Buzzard', Account=new Account(Master_Id__c='Blog Acc 8'));
```

I think I'm doing the same thing but I get this error when I try to instantiate parent:

> Illegal assignment from Revenue_Pipeline__c to Id

I have one method where I'm creating the parent record:

```
public static void actions(List<Project_Submission__c> projSubList)
{
    List<Revenue_Pipeline__c> revPipeToUpsert = new List<Revenue_Pipeline__c>();
    List<Revenue_Pipeline_Schedule__c> revPipeSchedule = new List<Revenue_Pipeline_Schedule__c>();

    for(Project_Submission__c ps : projSubList)
    {
        Date launch = ps.Target_Launch_Date__c.toStartOfMonth();
        String fy = String.valueOf(launch.year());
        Date endDate = getfiscalEndDate(fy);
        Date startDate = getfiscalStartDate(fy);

        if(ps.Year_1_Commercial_Budget__c != null)
        {
            String ext = ps.Id + '-' + 'CommercialBudget';

            Revenue_Pipeline__c revPipe = new Revenue_Pipeline__c();
            revPipe.External_Id__c = ext;
            revPipe.NPD_Forecast_Category__c = 'Commercial Budget';

            revPipeSchedule.addAll(createschedule(ps.Id, launch, endDate, ps.Year_1_Commercial_Budget__c, ps.CurrencyIsoCode, ext));
        }
```

Then another method where I am creating the children

```
public static List<Revenue_Pipeline_Schedule__c> createSchedule(Id projSubId, Date startDate, Date endDate, Decimal price, String cur, String ext)
{
    List<Revenue_Pipeline_Schedule__c> revenueScheduleList = new List<Revenue_Pipeline_Schedule__c>();

        Integer numOfMonths = startDate.monthsBetween(endDate) + 1;
        Decimal amount = price/numOfMonths;

        for(Integer i=0; i < numOfMonths; i++) 
        {
            Revenue_Pipeline_Schedule__c revSchedule = new Revenue_Pipeline_Schedule__c(
                Amount__c = amount,
                Date__c = startDate.addMonths(i),
                //Name = projSubId + ' - ' + Date__c.year() + '-' + Date__c.month(),
                CurrencyIsoCode = cur,
                Revenue_Pipeline__c = new Revenue_Pipeline__c(External_Id__c = ext)); <----- Error Here
            revenueScheduleList.add(revSchedule);           
        }
    return revenueScheduleList;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should be using the relationship name instead of the object name.

Replace below code which is giving the error

```
Revenue_Pipeline__c = new Revenue_Pipeline__c(External_Id__c = ext));
```

With

```
Revenue_Pipeline__r = new Revenue_Pipeline__c(External_Id__c = ext));
```

Note the __r in the above statement.

Comment: +1. Didn't realize at the first place that the relationship name was incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

The approach you are using: [Relating Records by Using an External ID](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_dml_nested_object.htm) has a pre-requisite that the parent record should exist.

In your current code, it seems you haven't yet inserted the parent `Revenue_Pipeline__c` record and are trying to reference the External Id field while creating the record for the child `Revenue_Pipeline__c`, and the primary issue for the error is that you have the field name incorrect. It should be the [relationship name](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_and_custom_objects.htm) of the field in this case.

In order for the approach below to work, you will need to ensure that the `Revenue_Pipeline__c` record has been inserted with the External Id value and that you will need to specify the relationship name for parent.

Your modified code should look as:

```
Revenue_Pipeline_Schedule__c revSchedule = 
    new Revenue_Pipeline_Schedule__c(
         ...
        // make sure a record for Revenue_Pipeline__c exists with External_Id__c = ext
         // and use the relationship name here __r
         Revenue_Pipeline__r = new Revenue_Pipeline__c(External_Id__c = ext));
```

As for how you can insert parent child records in the same flow, refer this from the linked documentation:

> If the parent record doesn’t exist, you can create it with a separate DML statement or by using the same DML statement as shown in [Creating Parent and Child Records in a Single Statement Using Foreign Keys](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_dml_foreign_keys.htm).

Comment: the compiler doesn't know that the exists or not, shouldn't it still compile with the logic?

Comment: As long as the fields are correct and the relationship defined, there should not be a compile time error for sure.

Comment: @DanWooding I just realized that you didn't have the relationship name while assigning it, and that was the reason of the issue. I have updated the answer to reflect that.